# Remove list from list of lists Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a list such as:

```
(def lst '((a b c) (d e) (f g h)))
```

I need to create a new list having removed one of the inner lists, 
I've tried

```
(remove '(d e) lst)
```

which returns

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

I've also tried

```
(filter (not= '(d e)) lst)
```

which returns

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: null
```

Comment: Please check out the Clojure docs; you might want to take a step back to familiarize yourself with how to learn the language. The docs for both state they expect a function, e.g., passing a quoted list to `remove` violates that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use [`filter`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter), note that the first argument has to be a function, so you could use

```
(filter #(not= '(d e) %) lst)
```

That's why you get the `ClassCastException`.

The same is true for [`remove`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/remove). You could also use [`partial`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial) instead of an anonymous function:

```
(remove (partial = '(d e)) lst)
```

Answer (score 4):

Both [filter](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter) and [remove](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/remove) functions expect first argument to be a predicate function. You could use [partial](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partial) function to transform operator `=` into a predicate:

```
(remove (partial = '(d e)) lst)
```